# How can I effectively patch up holes in insect screen?

Tags: home, repair

The biggest<sup>[*citation needed*]</sup> problem with children is that they like to rip holes in insect screens on doors/windows.

Replacing the insect screen is not always a viable solution (they cost money - especially since new one will be torn shortly again; or, the window is non-standard size and finding matching screen size is hard or impossible).

Assuming the rips aren't too big - under 10 inches long and 1 in inch wide, and most are much smaller - is there an effective way to patch up the rips?

The obvious solution (clear scotch tape) doesn't work because it refuses to stick to insect screen well and falls off easily.

I'm looking for a lifehack, not a professional repairman level solution.

Comment: Just curious, have you tried clear tape *on both sides of the screen so the pieces are sticking primarily to each other but secondarily to the screen*?

Comment: @sidney - no, but I'm not sure if that'd work well. If you tried, feel free to make that into an answer.

Comment: Not a lifehack, but you can generally just replace the screen material, not the frame, so you don't have to worry about finding the same size screen.  It's not difficult to do, and the material isn't expensive.  See the DIY site for instructions.

Answer (score 6):

Sewing will work.

Old fashioned stitches that will just to the job will do, but you might do some more fancy embroidery stitches to improve the looks of the screen, at the same time hiding the damage. Google ([search results here](https://www.google.com/search?q=hand%20sewing%20and%20embroidery%20stitches&espv=2&biw=870&bih=614&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj5hcbk2abRAhXecFAKHchhCgwQ_AUIBigB#imgrc=_)) on -hand sewing and embroidery stitches- for some options for sewing and embroidery stitches.

The [feather stitch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Featherstitch) will do both, basic repair as well as decoration. Use green yarn for the actual repair and head it with some bright colours for a flowerhead.
The more damages, the more flowers the screen will get.

If the kids are old enough they might even enjoy the act of repairing the screen, if you put it to them the right way.
(Some kids will never, others may ask you to teach them embroidery.)

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way is to use duct tape on both sides of the tear.

The "normal" way to repair a screen is cut a patch from fresh screen and then weave it over the tear using wire thread. A curved needle with a fairly large eye is needed for this.

Answer (score 0):

For tears where all the material is still intact, you can use a stapler to quickly "stitch" the material in place. You'll need a piece of metal (or a second stapler) to bend the staples shut. Just put the stapler on one side of the mesh, and the metal piece on the other.

---

For sections where the material is missing, you can use drywall tape mesh. It has similar sized holes as most screen doors, and comes in white. You'll almost definitely need to staple this in place, using the same method as for tears.

Answer (score -1):

You could do two hacks for this issue as a solution but it depends on the size of the hole.

1. If the size is very much small, you can surely go for this. You could arrange a used bubble gum(for this, you itself can have one and use the same afterward). Enlarge it using your fingers so as it fits the holes size. Then fit over the hole. Afterward, you could wash off your hands and let the patch dry for 1 day. Patched bubble gum will become a good obstruction for insects in terms of its material after a good dry. Furthermore, if this hole gets the attraction, you can color it with fabric paint to suit the entire insect screen.
2. You can use this solution if the patch is not a hole but a long cut. Arrange steel wire like this.I do not know the exact name of this, but you can use this to tie and make anything stay strong. You could hold back the two section of insect screen that is peeling off because of cut. If you see it awkward, you could insert the same as a design on both ends. [image]